# MyriadPro: Double dash not replaced by en dash

Tags: fonts, minionpro

I've installed the Minion/Myriad Pro fonts. While Minion works fine in this regard, Myriad shows unexpected behaviour: Compiling with `pdflatex`, two dashes `--` are not replaced by an en dash `–`.

How would I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{Myriad-LF}

\begin{document}
    test -- test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) and the `MyriadPro` package, it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{MyriadPro}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
    test -- test
\end{document}
```

[image: MyriadPro example]

You don't need the `MinionPro` package for that, of course.

Comment: Thanks, that works. In my installation the package is `Myridad` (no Pro), could you double-check that?

Comment: @dgs What is the source of your package? I'm sure mine is called `MyriadPro` and I cannot imagine how it would be renamed automatically.

Comment: I followed an installation guide on [latex-community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/download/file.php?id=6461) which references the Korean TUG's MyriadPro package. The package name includes -Pro, the `.sty` however does not.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is to replace `--` by `\textendash\`.